# Sync and open all tabs across android and desktop

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

I use Firefox on android and desktop (Ubuntu). Is it possible to sync (I do that) and automatically open same tabs on both devices? Is any extension for that?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox go to Options > Firefox Account > Sync settings.  As long as you have an account you can do this on all devices you wish to sync tabs.